# Incorporating Untracked Changes Into a File With the same name in a Git repository

Tags: git

I have made a number of changes to an HTML file and it's associated CSS file outside of the Git environment. Now I want to safely update the files that are being tracked inside of the Git repository.

I am hoping to get some guidance for this aspect of Git before attempting anything.

Comment: Just try it, for gosh sakes.  You SHOULD have made the changes directly to the files in the repository.  That's the whole point of using git -- you don't need a separate copy.  Remember that, even if you screw up your repo, you can just wipe it clean and clone another fresh copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are already tracked and you have committed their current state, just replace them with the edited versions and then do an add-and-commit as usual.

Git doesn't care how or where files got edited; it just sees that their content has changed. And a commit is simply a snapshot of the state of the whole project; again, how the project came to be in that state is no business or concern of Git's.